# How to use an assembly that is already loaded in memory, and regardless of its version?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, dependency-management

**My Scenario and Goal**

I'm working in PowerShell with a third-party module that loads assembly X.

I want to extend what X can do, either by providing extension methods or by taking instances of classes from X as input. Therefore I am developing a new assembly Y in Visual Studio. This is dependent on X since it uses classes provided by X. I'll load Y via `Add-Type` in my PowerShell session.

**My Technical Wish**

I want module Y to use whatever version of X is **already loaded into memory** independent of its version. Just take what is there and pretend the interfaces in X haven't changed.

This way module X can evolve (its API is stable, but there are regular updates) and I don't care because Y keeps working.

How can I do this? (Hopefully without losing too much tooling like Intellisense.)

Answer (score 0):

you can use AppDomain.GetAssemblies to get a list of assemblies loaded in memory (scoped to the app domain.)  And Assembly.LoadFrom to load the one return in the list from GetAssemblies.

Comment: I'm worried about the further development experience. Can I get type checking, Intellisense etc. when working in Visual Studio? Or would I need to do everything via Reflection?